# Unable to execute selenium webdriver with robot framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am getting the following error while trying to get selenium webdriver working with robot framework.

```
WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

I have downloaded the webdriver executable and have put it into path, but am still getting the error.

Comment: Try to put the path next to the browser executable, and put that path to path.

Comment: Based on the little info you provide, I assume you are trying to use Firefox 47+ with Selenium2Library. If you are using the keyword `Open Browser` you do not have much control on the definitions for webdriver. In that case you will need to use `Create Webdriver`. Note that Selenium2Library is not yet detecting if you are using Selenium3 (3.0.1) or Selenium2 (2.53.6). Please post here the minimal Robot Framework test file which reveals the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Helio, here are my test file contents:

*** Settings ***
Documentation     A resource file with reusable keywords and variables.
Library           Selenium2Library
...
*** Keyword ***
Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}
    Go To Login Page

Valid Login
    Open Browser To Login Page
    Input Username    asagent

Comment: Using Firefox version 47+ is not so simple with Selenium2Library. That is why you can't get it running with `Open Browser` keyword. You have to see documentation for `Create Webdriver`, and how to create a dictionary of desired capabilities, where you would include the path to your Firefox program. If you don't want to much trouble, you may, use Firefox ESR (45.5.0) and selenium 2.53.6, or use other browsers like for example Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to robot framework. If you are able to open firefox using selenium python without giving path of firefox binary then it works fine in robot framework as well.

By default selenium will look into the path - C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\

Please install firefox using the link - http://filehippo.com/download_firefox/67599/

Answer (score 0):

I had Firefox installed at the default location itself - C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\, but I was still getting this error. I got it fixed by adding the Firefox location using FirefoxOptions class

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

I'm using the latest versions of Selenium, Firefox and GeckoDriver as specified in this article - http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Answer (score 0):

I got the the same error,

For firefox on windows:

put below dir in you Path

C:\Users\abc\appData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\